# Take Picture/Video of Logon Screen

Tags: windows-7, login

How might I take multiple pictures or videos of my computers log on screen?

It is unclear of me how to do such.  PrintScreen doesn't appear to work.

**The linked question has no accepted answer as is.**

Comment: possibly try this [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/113267/how-to-take-screenshots-of-the-windows-logon-screen-2-geeky-tricks/)

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like There appears to be no accepted answer.  I will have to try each one individually to see if they work.

Comment: @William Agreed but doesn't mean that you cannot try suggested answers

Comment: @William Try [Joxi](http://joxi.net/download/) the screenshot taking tool, its been a while i have used a windows but remember being able to fire up screenshot using keyboard shortcuts at login screen.

Comment: Run Windows 7 in a VM, easy to take screenshots now.

Comment: @William It wasn't Joxi, it was [Jing from TechSmith](https://www.techsmith.com/jing.html)